# Facebook API Insight Metrics Daily graph API

Tags: facebook, graph, metrics, facebook-insights

Hi Guys I am hoping someone could help me.

I have been toying around with the Facebook API for our company's facebook analytics page.  I am looking to get information on the likes, shares, impressions etc and store directly to a database

I have been able to pull this information back using the Graph API Explorer.  Now I want to be able to pull the information back for say today.  When I add today's date in it only relates to the actual posts that were posted today, not *today's activity.* if that makes sense.

An example of this is if I had liked a post today that was created 2 days ago, it doesnt show in in today's activity, but the activity from 2 days ago.

The code I have been using is: 
       `feed?fields=comments.limit(1).summary(true),likes.limit(1).summary(true)&since=2016-10-28`

Just wondering if I am missing something as surely should be an easy way of getting todays actual activity from users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example isn't fetching Insights, you're fetching the posts visible on the page's Timeline, then asking for a count of the comments and likes

There's a totally different API for fetching Insights data: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/platforminsights/page

This is the same API used by the Insights UI, so for the same set of metrics/dates, it should give identical results to the UI

Comment: Thanks for that.  I am looking at the insights UI, and as you say its giving me the same info as above.  Is there a way to get the info a need that you know of easily?  When I look at the Insights UI, it will show me just the posts from today and their associated metrics, not the actual activity for today if that makes sense.  Is it possible?

Comment: Does the response to `/v2.8/<POST_ID>/insights` return the metrics you're looking for? 
Those should be the stats for the current day for that post ID (the specific metrics available for posts are those listed on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/insights prefixed with `post_`

Comment: no it doesnt.  When I try to use a POST_ID comes back with an error.  When I use the PAGE_ID it will display metrics on posts created today.  This is not what I need.  I need the metrics on the activity today, regardless if the post was created today.  Example: PAGE_ID/feed?fields=insights.metric(post_impressions_unique )&limit=100&period=day&since=2016-10-28 - This will only bring data on impression on posts CREATED today not the impressions across all posts today.  I want impressions today across all the posts whether the posts were created today, last week etc

Comment: I hope I have made sense!  Im very new to the FB stuff!